# ALSO iOS Safari memory leak when loading/unloading HTML5 <video>

Tags: javascript, html, video, memory-leaks

I've never encountered this problem until now but...
I have the same exact problem as this and it's BAD. I wind up sending infinite data very quickly and it leaks so badly that I can't call other scripts on my page.

I am aware of the solution to their problem but I have a slightly different question. How would I go about keeping my video and allowing it to play but stopping the memory leak? If I set the source variable to null I lose the video entirely and I'd like it to simply load, play, and loop a video without sending 10 gigs of data

-_-

Here's what I have in html:

```
<video muted autoplay loop id="IceCreamOrgy">
      <source src="/assets/Section1/Ice_Cream_Orgy_Final.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

and in js:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("IceCreamOrgy").src = ''
}, 3000)
```

is not what I want to do... but where I'm at in debugging was to watch it play for [time] and then disappear, ugh.

I wouldn't care so much but it's a 350MB video and literally sends forever.

Can I load the video, allow it to play (looping would be nice), AND not have to choose between lose it entirely or keep loading for the long duration of playback and then losing it?